# Hosting Multiple Rails Applications with Passenger Phusion - memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, passenger

I want to reduce my server cost by virtually hosting many RoR development applications servers on a single machine, with the databases hosted elsewhere. Each application uses a lot of memory when it's fully loaded, so my concern is that this won't scale well.

So my question -- for any passenger phusion experts out there -- is will passenger keep one fully loaded instance of itself in memory for each application, regardless of how long it's been since that application has been used? If so, is there any way to tell phusion to swap out the least recently used host when necessary to conserve memory?

Usage pattern: I don't expect more than one or two of these applications to be in active use at once, and I don't mind if it takes a long time to load the page initially, as long as it's snappy on subsequent page loads (since these are dev instances).

Here's a spec of my current setup:

-Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7, with copy-on-write enabled
-Rails 2.3.18 (I know it's old school...)
-Passenger 3.0.11
-AWS EC2 for application hosting
-AWS RDS for DB hosting

Any advice on how I can do this in a memory efficient fashion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Phusion Pasenger *already* shuts down processes to conserve memory by default. See these configuration options:

http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize
http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMinInstances
http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerPoolIdleTime

Comment: Thanks Hongli. So I guess it's "PassengerMinInstances 0" in each virtualhost, and possibly adjust the idle time?